# .htaccess header edit set-cookie not work with laravel

Tags: laravel, apache, httponly

My project need to run a security test requested by the client.

I use OWASP ZAP to run the test.

and it'll given back `cookie No HttpOnly Flag` warning, and it happended because of the "X-XSRF TOKEN" cookie didn't set httponly flag.

I did some research, and I know about this cookie didn't set httponly for javascript librarys like axios to use it.

but I use laravel 5.5, and in initial project, there is a great mechanism to let javascript library get this token without operate cookie directly, by meta flag:

```php
......

// layout.blade.php 
 <!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

......
```

and in index.js:

```
/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

so it should be work fine even if `XSRF-TOKEN` 's `httponly` flag set to true.

I trace src code, and realize that I can modify just one line to make it work.
and somenoe already open a pr on github to solve this question:

> https://github.com/ametad/framework/commit/2241b020ae3001ce5dabc1b7c5ea1514ff7f2e33

but I don't feel free to modify source code of framework,
so I try to modify cookie header via apache server (by `public/.httaccess`)

```sh
# public/.httaccess
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always edit Set-Cookie: (.*) "$1, httponly"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</ifModule>
```

but `Header always edit Set-Cookie: (.*) "$1, httponly"` didn't work for me.
below this line is all work, just set-cookie not work.

any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it generally isn't necessary to have the `XSRF-TOKEN` be http only. This cookie is encrypted (all Laravel cookies get encrypted) therefore even if a client does gain access to it, it does not actually contain any useful information.

You can override the default `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware with your own:

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier {
    protected function addCookieToResponse($request, $response)
    {
        $config = config('session');
        $response->headers->setCookie(
            new Cookie(
                'XSRF-TOKEN', $request->session()->token(), $this->availableAt(60 * $config['lifetime']),
                $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'], $config['http_only'], false, $config['same_site'] ?? null
            )
        );
        return $response;
    }

}
```

You can then replace the framework `VerifyCsrfToken` in `Http/Kernel.php` with your own overrriden one.

The downside to this is when you upgrade your Laravel version you will need to ensure your overriden class will still be compatible with the base class.

Comment: I got it, and it's a great solution that I don't need to modify laravel source code.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with modifying cookies in .htaccess but generally with apache it usually boils down to either disabled modules or syntax quirks .